# Remove element from array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I have  following  array of objects.

```
[{"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":39,"sId":18,"disabled":false}]
```

In which  some records are antithesis  ex. 1st element  and  4th which has same rId, gId, and sId but disabled flag is  opposite.
I want to eliminate all such records.

My expected array is  `{"rId":24,"gId":39,"sId":18,"disabled":false}` (eliminate all antithesis records)

I tried following code  but it is giving me wrong  output.

```
arrOfObj=[{"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":39,"sId":18,"disabled":false}]


$.each(arrOfObj,function (index1,firstObj) {
    $.each(arrOfObj,function (index2,secondObj) {
        if(index1>= index2){
            return true;
        }
        var areObjAntithesis=firstObj.rId===secondObj.rId && firstObj.gId===secondObj.gId
           && firstObj.sId===secondObj.sId && firstObj.disabled!==secondObj.disabled;

        if(areObjAntithesis){
            arrOfObj.splice(index1,1);
            arrOfObj.splice(index2,1)
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```

Is there any elegant way to achieve expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `map()` and `filter()`

```js
var data = [{"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":39,"sId":18,"disabled":false}]
 
var ar = data.map(function(e) {
  return e.rId + '|' + e.gId + '|' + e.sId;
});
 
var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  var key = e.rId + '|' + e.gId + '|' + e.sId;
  return ar.indexOf(key) == ar.lastIndexOf(key);
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://underscorejs.org/#where and do like that:

```
var newArrOfObj=_.where(arrOfObj, {disabled:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `array.filter` and check count and only return elements which have more than 1 value and if values are same or have only one value

```js
var data = [{"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":39,"sId":18,"disabled":false}]

var result = data.filter(function(outer){
  var disablesValues = []
  
  var _r = data.filter(function(inner){
    if(inner.gId === outer.gId && inner.sId === outer.sId){
      if(disablesValues.indexOf(inner.disabled) < 0)
        disablesValues.push(inner.disabled);
      return true;
    }
  });
  
  return _r.length === 1 || disablesValues.length === 1
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could two loops, one for collecting and one for filtering the array.

```js
var data = [{ "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 20, "disabled": false }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 19, "disabled": false }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 50, "disabled": false }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 20, "disabled": true }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 19, "disabled": true }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 50, "disabled": true }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 39, "sId": 18, "disabled": false }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    getKey = function (o) { return ["rId", "gId", "sId"].map(function (k) { return o[k]; }).join('|'); },
    result;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = getKey(a);
    hash[key] = (hash[key] || 0) + (a.disabled || -1);
});

result = data.filter(function (a) {
    return hash[getKey(a)];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var data = [{ "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 20, "disabled": false }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 19, "disabled": false }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 50, "disabled": false }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 20, "disabled": true }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 19, "disabled": true }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 40, "sId": 50, "disabled": true }, { "rId": 24, "gId": 39, "sId": 18, "disabled": false }],
    result = data.filter(a =>
        !data.find(b => ["rId", "gId", "sId"].every(k => 
            a[k] === b[k]
        ) && a.disabled !== b.disabled));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is *functional programming* style ES6 solution, which will deal with more repetitions as well, counting how the number of disabled and enabled objects balance annihilate each other:

```js
function eliminateOpposites(arr) {
    return [...arr
        .map( o => ({ o, k: JSON.stringify({ rId:o.rId, gId:o.gId, sId:o.sId }) }) )
        .reduce( (acc, o) => acc.set(o.k, (acc.get(o.k) || 0)+ (+o.o.disabled || -1)),
                             new Map() )]
        .filter( ([k, balance]) => balance )
        .map( ([k, balance]) => Object.assign(JSON.parse(k), {disabled: balance>0}));
}

// Sample data
var arrOfObj=[
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":false},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":20,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":19,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":40,"sId":50,"disabled":true},
 {"rId":24,"gId":39,"sId":18,"disabled":false}]
 
console.log(eliminateOpposites(arrOfObj));
```

It makes use of hashing, which leads to a *O(n)* algorithm instead of *O(n²)*, which is the case with `indexOf`-style solutions.

`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are used to compose and decompose the composite key values. The string version serves as key in a `Map`, in which each entry logs a count of disabled versus enabled occurrences of the same key. The `.filter()` call kicks out the cases where the count of disabled and enabled occurrences is the same (could be 2 versus 2), and the final `.map()` turns the kay/value array back to the expected format.